# Eclipse Segfault (OSX)

Tags: eclipse, macos, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to start eclipse but it crashes after the splash screen and before workspace selection.
This is version: eclipse-java-indigo-SR2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64 on Mac OSX 10.6.8
Launching the eclipse application or executing the alias from a shell ./eclipse (or Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse) results in a segfault.

```
$ ./eclipse
Invalid memory access of location 0x10 rip=0x7fff84ea3164

Segmentation fault
```

However, it runs successfully as the super user

```
$ sudo ./eclipse
Password:
```

This is fine for now, but running eclipse under sudo does not seem like a good idea.
To make this stranger still, this installation of eclipse worked fine a few months ago and I can't remember changing anything relevant.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Could be a software update from Apple borked your Java installation, although I'd be a little surprised. I run 10.6.8 right now on 2 different MacBooks and about 4 different versions of Eclipse, all without problems. What do you get in response to `java -version` in a command shell? How about `which java`?

Comment: /usr/bin/java and java version "1.6.0_29" / Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-10M3527) / Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode)

Comment: That's the same version I have, so I don't know what might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Before taking the more drastic step of re-installing Java on Mac OS X [not always so simple :( ..  ], I just reinstalled Eclipse and ADT - and it worked fine after that.

In my case, I got this error trying to start Eclipse

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

.. it appeared in my Eclipse ADT setup after I updated the Android SDK for Google Play Services, and then tried to run Installation of update from "Check For Updates".  Restarting the computer did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I would try re-installing Java. The Apple installer might thwart you, but [this](http://www.kunaldua.com/blog/2006/06/how-to-force-reinstall-java-on-mac-os-x/) can help get past it.

I'd suggest getting the Java Developer package from Apple, as it includes Javadoc and source for the core libraries.